# Parse a raw IRC message

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

In the IRC protocol, raw messages look similar to this:

```
command arg1 arg2 :arg3 with spaces :arg4 with spaces :arg5
```

In a shell environment (e.g. bash), that would be equivalent to:

```
command arg1 arg2 "arg3 with spaces" "arg4 with spaces" arg5
```

The format specification is as follows:

- Raw messages will only contain printable ASCII characters (ordinals 32-126).
- Raw messages will start with a command, which will not contain any spaces.
- Any number of arguments may follow a command. Arguments are delimited by one or more spaces followed by a colon (`<space>:` and `<space><space>:` are both valid delimiters).

  - Any arguments that do not contain spaces may omit the colon from the delimiter so long as all previous arguments (if any) have omitted the colon.
- Colons will not appear within arguments or commands.
- Arguments will not begin with a space.

For example, these are all valid raw messages:

```
join #foo #bar #baz
msg person hi
msg #channel :hello world
help :how do I use IRC
foo bar :baz bip :abc def :ghi
```

These are all invalid raw messages:

```
error :n:o colons within arguments
error ::need spaces between colons
:error no colons in commands
error non-ASCII character Ω
```

Given a valid raw IRC message as input, output a list containing the command and the arguments, properly parsed.

### Test Cases

```
"join #foo #bar #baz" -> ["join", "#foo", "#bar", "#baz"]
"msg person hi" -> ["msg", "person", "hi"]
"msg #channel :hello world" -> ["msg", "#channel", "hello world"]
"help :how do I use IRC" -> ["help", "how do I use IRC"]
foo bar :baz bip :abc def :ghi :xyz -> ["foo", "bar", "baz bip", "abc def", "ghi", "xyz"]
```

Comment: Could the final argument end with spaces?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes

Comment: Can we assume that input will be valid?

Comment: @Titus Yes, that was the goal of defining what constitutes valid input.

Comment: Does the output have to be a flat list?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills What do you have in mind?

Comment: `(("foo", "bar"), ("baz bip", "abc def", "ghi", "xyz"))`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills No, you need to preserve the spaces in arguments

Comment: I was asking about the `()`, that is `((0,1),(2,3,4,5))` vs `(0,1,2,3,4,5)`. If you look you will see `"baz bip"` which means it is a string with a space in the middle.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Oh, I missed that. Blame mobile and tiny screens. I'm still going to say flat lists only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;⁷œṣ⁾ :µḢḲ;œr€⁶ỴF$€
```

A monadic link that returns a list.

Note: As a full program the implicit print that Jelly performs may be a little confusing in this case, since a list containing strings (really lists of characters in Jelly) is printed as if it were a single string. So, for completeness here are test harnesses employing the quick `Ç` which calls the previous link monadically:

1. [`Ṿ`](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KBt8WT4bmj4oG-IDrCteG4ouG4sjvFk3Ligqzigbbhu7RGJOKCrArDh-G5vg&input=&args=Zm9vIGJhciA6YmF6IGJpcCA6YWJjIGRlZiA6Z2hpIDp4eXo) shows the Jelly representation of a list of character lists;
2. [`Y`](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KBt8WT4bmj4oG-IDrCteG4ouG4sjvFk3Ligqzigbbhu7RGJOKCrArDh1k&input=&args=Zm9vIGJhciA6YmF6IGJpcCA6YWJjIGRlZiA6Z2hpIDp4eXo) joins the list with line feeds;
3. [`ŒṘ`](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KBt8WT4bmj4oG-IDrCteG4ouG4sjvFk3Ligqzigbbhu7RGJOKCrArDh8WS4bmY&input=&args=Zm9vIGJhciA6YmF6IGJpcCA6YWJjIGRlZiA6Z2hpIDp4eXo) shows the underlying Python representation (showing the actual lists of characters).

#### How?

Handling the edge case of possible trailing spaces for the ultimate argument (the only one which may have trailing spaces) is quite an expense at 6 bytes; maybe there is a shorter way?

```
;⁷œṣ⁾ :µḢḲ;œr€⁶ỴF$€ - Link expecting a single list of characters as input
;                   - concatenate
 ⁷                  - a line feed (to avoid right trimming spaces from ultimate argument)
  œṣ                - split on sublists equal to
    ⁾ :             -     two character list [' ',':']
       µ            - monadic chain separation (call the split result z)
        Ḣ           - head - pop first element (modifies z)
         Ḳ          - split at spaces
          ;         - concatenate with z
              ⁶     - space
           œr€      - right-strip from €ach
                 $€ - last two links as a monad for €ach
               Ỵ    -     split on line feeds
                F   -     flatten (removes the line feed from the beginning)
```

Comment: How does this handle `<space><space>:`?

Comment: @isaacg - thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed it up, although it opened up an edge case I had to address too.

Comment: I think you can add the [`Ṙ×0`](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=O-KBt8WT4bmj4oG-IDrCteG4ouG4sjvFk3Ligqzigbbhu7RGJOKCrArDh-G5mOG5m-KAnA&args=Zm9vIGJhciA6YmF6IGJpcCA6YWJjIGRlZiA6Z2hpIDp4eXo) test harness too.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 87 bytes

```
$a=($s=preg_split)("# +:#",$argv[1]);array_splice($a,0,1,$s("# +#",$a[0]));print_r($a);
```

The first regex splits the argument by one or more spaces followed by a colon.
The second regex splits the first element by one or more spaces with no colon.
`array_splice` replaces the first element with the result of the second `preg_split`.
`print_r` prints the resulting array.

**function version for testing**

```
$cases=[
    "join #foo #bar #baz" => ["join", "#foo", "#bar", "#baz"],
    "msg person hi" => ["msg", "person", "hi"],
    "msg #channel :hello world" => ["msg", "#channel", "hello world"],
    "help :how do I use IRC" => ["help", "how do I use IRC"],
    "foo bar :baz bip :abc def :ghi :xyz" => ["foo", "bar", "baz bip", "abc def", "ghi", "xyz"],
];
function i($argv_1_){$a=($s=preg_split)("# +:#",$argv_1_);array_splice($a,0,1,$s("# +#",$a[0]));return $a;}
foreach($cases as$x=>$e)
{
    $y=i($x);
    echo "case '$x': ['",join("','",$y),'"]: ',($y<>$e?"FAIL. Expected: ['". join("','",$e)."']":OK),"\n";
}
```

Comment: what should i learn from that downvote?

Comment: I'm not sure why whoever downvoted did as they did, but maybe it didn't work for all test cases?

Comment: @Downgoat Or maybe someone just doesn´t like my nose. It doesn´t check the input for correctness; but I don´t see that required anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 24 bytes

```
M!`:.+?(?=\s+:|$)|\S+
:
```

(note there is a trailing newline)

[Try it online!](http://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=retina&p=81VMsNLTttewt40p1raqUdGsiQnW5rLi@p@Wn6@QlFikYJWUWKWQlFmgYJWYlKyQkpqmYJWekalgVVFZBQA)

Comment: Added that new line. Could you pop an explanation in at some point?

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>43</s> 34 bytes

```
$a,$b=$args-split' +:';-split$a;$b
```

This `-split`s the input string `$args` on the regex `+:` (i.e., one or more spaces and a colon), stores the left-most (i.e., first result) into `$a` and any remaining results into `$b`. We then need to `-split` `$a` on spaces (here done by leveraging that whitespace is the default for unary `-split`), and that's left on the pipeline. We then simply put `$b` on the pipeline. Output via implicit `Write-Output` inserts a newline between elements.

#### Test cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\parse-raw-irc.ps1 'join #foo #bar #baz'
join
#foo
#bar
#baz

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\parse-raw-irc.ps1 'msg person hi'
msg
person
hi

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\parse-raw-irc.ps1 'msg channel :hello world'
msg
channel
hello world

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\parse-raw-irc.ps1 'help :how do I use IRC'
help
how do I use IRC

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\parse-raw-irc.ps1 'foo bar :baz bip :abc def :ghi :xyz'
foo
bar
baz bip
abc def
ghi
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
Flatten@MapAt[s=StringSplit,#,1]&@s[#," :"]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 140 bytes (excluding sample usage)

```
void p(char*m){char*c=strchr(m,':');if(c) {*c=0;c++;} 
char*n=strtok(m," ");while(n) {puts(n);n=strtok(NULL," ");}
if(c){puts(c);}}
```

Sample usage:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void parse(char*msg){char*c=strchr(msg,':');if(c) {*c=0;c++;} 
char*n=strtok(msg," ");while(n){puts(n);n=strtok(NULL," ");}
if(c){puts(c);}}
main(){char msg[]="sample : abcnsjd hajs";parse(msg);}
```

Try me: http://codepad.org/GQ51MO4l

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)   First of all, you should format your golfed code the same way as your 'sample usage' code. You could turn every name that is over 1 characters to 1, ex. `parse` to `p` and `msg` to `m`. Useless whitespaces could be removed from after `if(c)` (both cases) and `while(n)`.

Comment: I count 131 bytes, and there's still extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 49 bytes

This is my first entry on PPCG, any input appreciated!

```
(s,[a,...b]=s.split(/ +:/))=>a.split` `.concat(b)
```

---

**EDIT History:**

- Thanks @Mego for saving 2 bytes by making it an anonymous function.
- Replaced `\s` with   to save 1 byte.
- Thanks @BassdropCumberwubwubwub for showing me the `` split` ` `` syntax and the `[a,...b]=array_expression_here` syntax. I didn't know these were possible, thank you very much! Very clever!

#### Test snippet

```js
let f = (s,[a,...b]=s.split(/ +:/))=>a.split` `.concat(b)
```

```html
<input id=I type="text" size=70 value="command arg1 arg2 :arg3 with spaces :arg4 with spaces :arg5"><button onclick="console.log(f(I.value))">Run</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The only improvement I see is that you can drop the `f=` to make it an anonymous function, which are allowed on the site by default.

Comment: You can write `split(" ")` as `split\` \`` to save 2 bytes

Comment: Actually, even shorter like this `(s,[a,...b]=s.split(/ +:/))=>a.split\` \`.concat(b)`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <del>64</del> 60 bytes

```
import re;a=re.split(' +:',input());print a[0].split()+a[1:]
```

Edit:
Requires quoted input to use `input`.
Preserves trailing spaces on last argument.

Comment: Since we allow input to be wrapped in quotes, you can use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`

Comment: Needs to handle the edge case of [the final argument having trailing spaces](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101988/parse-a-raw-irc-message#comment247687_101988)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>49</s>  47 bytes

```perl6
{m/(<-[\ :]>+)+%%" "+":"?(.+?)*%[" "+":"]$/.flat}
```

[Perl 6](https://perl6.org) version of the [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101988/parse-a-raw-irc-message/102200#102200)

```perl6
{$/=.split(/" "+":"/);|$0.split(" "),|$/[1..*]}
```

The to `|`s are there to flatten the list.

### the first entry expanded:

```perl6
{    # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  m/               # regex match implicitly against ｢$_｣

      (               # capture
        <-[\ :]>+     # at least one non-space non-colon character
      )+              # at least once

    %%                # separated (with optional trailing separator)

      " "+            # by at least one space


    ":"?              # optionally match a colon ( needed for rest of regex )


      (               # capture
        .+?           # at least one character as short as possible
      )*              # any number of times

    %                 # separated (no optional trailing separator)

      [ " "+ ":" ]    # by at least one space, and a colon


    $                 # match end of string (needed because of ｢.+?｣)
  /

 .flat         # flatten the captures
}
```